# What's the difference between C and Go when there are remains in stdin on programs exits

Tags: c, linux, go

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    return 0;
}
```

main.go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var n int
    fmt.Scan(&n)
}
```

```bash
root@82da6559c1c0:/code# go run main.go 
123x123
root@82da6559c1c0:/code# 123
bash: 123: command not found
root@82da6559c1c0:/code# gcc main.c -o main
root@82da6559c1c0:/code# ./main
123x123
root@82da6559c1c0:/code#
```

1. I want to konw why in Golang, `123` was inserted into my bash command. But in C it didn't? Was there any differecces? (I konw there were some characters remained in stdin)
2. I want to konw how can I make Golang behave like C does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `stdin` is buffered in C, so your `scanf` causes a larger read of the input (into a buffer).

In Go, `os.Stdin` is *not* buffered. If you want to achieve the same result as you see in the C program, you can wrap stdin in a [`bufio.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Reader), although whether that has exactly the same behavior as whatever C standard library you're using will need testing.